# Writing output of describe() and a text label to same Excel sheet in Python

Tags: python, excel

This is a continuation of a related question here: [Creating a blank worksheet and adding text to that new worksheet using Python, ExcelWriter and openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453420/creating-a-blank-worksheet-and-adding-text-to-that-new-worksheet-using-python-e/58480297?noredirect=1#comment103297998_58480297)

I am trying to write the output of a df.describe() to an specific cell in Excel using ExcelWriter with the openpyxl engine and then add a descriptive label to the cell above.  I am finding that various methods produce a duplicate tab with "_1" appended.

My code is this:

```
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"data validation for {FNum}_{FName}.xlsx",engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        DWoldfiltered.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Previous_DW_load")
        DWfiltered.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Latest_DW_load")

        book = writer.book
        sheet = book.create_sheet("Summary_Data")
        sheet.cell(1,1).value = "Latest Load"
        sheet.cell(2,1).value = DWfiltered.describe()
    writer.save()
```

However, when I execute it I get the error message

```
"raise Value Error("Cannot convert {0!r} to excel".to format(value))
```

The data I'm working with has 0 in the first three columns with NaN for subsequent descriptive values, replace 0 with np.nan and then dropna doesn't change the error message.

The data I'm trying to paste is a data frame based on the describe() function and looks like this:

```
         Col 1    Col 2    Col 3       col 4   Col 5
count        0        0        0         119    119
mean       NaN      NaN      NaN    24229.78  66645  
std        NaN      NaN      NaN       27877  74617
min        NaN      NaN      NaN        1080    457
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an error linked to this line. sheet.cell(2,1).value = DWfiltered.describe(). I will do something like this. sheet.cell(2,1) = DWfiltered.describe().to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Summary_Data", start_row=2, start_col=1)

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the complete error traceback report in your question.

Comment: @Xukraro Thanks for the reminder.  I kept trying various approaches which produced different error messages, so didn't want to overload the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your error is related to 0.

I will do something like this instead.

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(f"data validation for {FNum}_{FName}.xlsx",engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:

    DWoldfiltered.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Previous_DW_load") 
    DWfiltered.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Latest_DW_load") 

    summary = pd.DataFrame({"Latest Load" : []})
    summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Summary_Data")    
    describe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ="Summary_Data", startrow=2, startcol=1)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I changed the "start_row" and "end_row" TO 'startrow' and 'endrow', but the describe DF appears on a tab "Summary_Data1" and the labels appear on a tab "Summary_Data".   I'm beginning to think about closing saving the document, reopening it to apply the text in a separate stage.

Comment: Hmm - that produces two copes of "Summary_Data", "Summary_Data1" and then "Summary_Data2" and "SummaryData3"  Also if the file doesn't exist before the code is run, it crashes saying it can't find the file.  If there was a way to apply the append _selectively_, then this would work.  Your efforts are appreciated but I'm thinking save the file, reopen it and then apply the labels separately...

Comment: Lets try by using only df, see my last update. If it doesn't work, go head with your idea.

Comment: Your code did work. so thanks for that.  I hadn't quite understood that the text was being converted into a DataFrame, whereas I was still fixated on appending a string.

Comment: @GregWilliams I transform the text to a column name in dataframe just to get access to the method `to_excel`. In the excel, only a trying appears as the Dataframe is empty, so no index, and no value expect the column.